# How can I continue in Fabric if a command does not finish or succeed?

Tags: python, fabric

Sometimes this code prompts a password, then I would like to just skip to next line of code in 10 seconds.

```
run_in(node, 'sudo init 0')
```

I regularly have an issue where I want to continue on errors.

Ansible has ignore_errors: True. How to do this in Fabric?

Answer (score 0):

Is flag *warn_only* what you need? If set to *True* it skips errors and only shows warnings. You can use it as block only for lines of code which you want to skip errors.  See more in [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/env.html) here

Example:

```
from fabric.api import settings
with settings(warn_only=True):
     # your code here
```